# Convergence of a real sequence (stochastic approximation)

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, stochastic-approximation

Let $(\gamma_n)_{n \geq 1}$ be a sequence of positive real numbers satisfying $$\sum_{n \in \mathbb{N}}\gamma_n = + \infty \text{ and }\sum_{n \in \mathbb{N}}\gamma_n^2 < + \infty$$

I would like to know if the sequence $(u_n)_{n \geq 1}$ defined by
$$\forall n \in \mathbb{N},~u_n = \sum_{i=1}^n \gamma_i \prod_{j=i+1}^n (1-\gamma_j)^2$$ is bounded

**Note**

I have proven that with the same conditions on $(\gamma_n)_{n \geq 1}$, we have $$ \sum_{i=1}^{t} \gamma_i^2 \prod_{j = i+1}^{t} (1-\gamma_j)^2 \underset{n \to \infty}{\longrightarrow} 0$$
using the fact that 
$\prod_{j = i+1}^{t} (1-\gamma_j)^2 = e^{2 \sum_{j = i+1}^{t} \ln(1-\gamma_j)} \leq e^{- 2 \sum_{j = i+1}^{t} \gamma_j}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I also posted [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/308451/convergence-of-a-real-sequence-stochastic-approximation) on MathOverflow. I am posting here the answer from Christian Remling.

> Yes, the sequence is bounded. As you already suggested yourself, it's
>   useful to estimate the product by $\exp \left( -2\sum_{k=j+1}^n
>  \gamma_k \right)$.
>
> The statement is clearest in its continuous version, for integrals:
>   then it's immediately obvious that $$ \int_1^N f(x) e^{-2\int_x^N
>  f(t)\, dt}\, dx = \frac{1}{2}\left( 1 - e^{-2\int_1^N f(t)\,
>  dt}\right) \to \frac{1}{2} . $$
>
> In the original setting, we can mimic the integration by writing $$
>  e^{-2\sum_{k=j+1}^n \gamma_k} - e^{-2\sum_{k=j}^n \gamma_k} =
>  e^{-2\sum_{k=j+1}^n \gamma_k} \left( 1 - e^{-2\gamma_j} \right) ,
>  \quad\quad\quad\quad (1) $$ and $1-e^{-2\gamma_j} = 2\gamma_j +
> > O(\gamma_j^2)$. The error term is summable and can be ignored, so we
>   can approximately replace the summands
>   $\gamma_je^{-2\sum_{k=j+1}^n\gamma_k}$ by ($1/2$ times) the LHS of
>   (1), and then the sum becomes telescoping.
>
> In fact, by keeping track more carefully of what the first step
>   (replacing the product with the exponential) does, we can show that
>   $u_n$ approaches a limit.